# Determine if FieldInfo is compiler generated backingfield

Tags: c#, reflection

The title pretty much says it all, how do I know if I'm getting a compiler generated backingfield for a {get; set;} property ?

I'm running this code to get my FieldInfos:

```
Class MyType
{
    private int foo;
    public int bar {get; private set; }
}

Type type = TypeOf(MyType);
foreach (FieldInfo fi in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    // Gets both foo and bar, however bar is called <bar>k__backingfield.
}
```

so the question is, can I somehow detect that the FieldInfo is a backingfield, without relying on checking its name ? (Which is pretty undocumented, and could be broken in next version of the framework)

Comment: Why do you need to know, out of curiosity? (it might affect the answer)

Comment: Well it's because I grab all FieldInfo and PropertyInfo of a specific type and store them in a dictionary.

I use it for a reflection based ORM (which I believe you sent me some dynamic code for once)

Anyway I'm pretty certain GetCustomAttributes will do the trick :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check `.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false);` on them.

Comment: Yup seems like the better choice :-)